# Combining two or more paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying out a simple 'point the error in a sentence quiz'. The code seems to work all fine but I would like the three parts of a sentence to appear as in a paragraph.

```
<p onclick="myFunction()">Being a holiday</p>
<p onclick="myFunction2()"> we decided to go for a picnic</p>
<p onclick="myFunction3()"> to the nearby park.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<img src='../images/right.jpg'>";
    }
    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<img src='../images/wrong.jpg'>";
    }
    function myFunction3() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<img src='../images/wrong.jpg'>";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put each sentence piece in individual `<span>` tags instead of `<p>` tags, and then set the `onclick` attribute on those `<span>` tags. Then just put all those in a single `<p>` tag:

```
<p>
  <span onclick="myFunction()">Being a holiday</span>
  <span onclick="myFunction2()"> we decided to go for a picnic</span>
  <span onclick="myFunction3()"> to the nearby park.</span>
</p>
```

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tp0yrwk8/1/